# ERROR in src\containers\Login.js Line 35:5: Parsing error: Unexpected token (35:5)

Tags: reactjs, django

Hello guys I'm new in React while watching a tutorial I'm getting this error and I checked it multiple times and compared it with the one in tutorial and can't find any difference. I'm trying to create a user authentication with Django and React. I'm using sublime text 3 as an editor and I have also Visual Studio Code installed. Should I install any extension to handle this problem? Can you help me with this parsing error?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


const Login = () => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    const { email, password } = formData;

    const onChange = e => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // login(email, password)
    };

    // Is the user Authenticated?
    // Redirect them to the home page

    return (
        <div className='container mt-5'>
            <h1>
                Sign in
            </h1>
            <p>
                Sign into your account
            </p>
            <form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e)}>
                <div className='form-group'
                    <input
                        className='form-control'
                        type='email'
                        placeholder='Email'
                        name='email'
                        value={email}
                        onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <div className='form-group'
                    <input
                        className='form-control'
                        type='password'
                        placeholder='Password'
                        name='password'
                        value={password} 
                        onChange={e => onChange(e)}
                        minLength='6'
                        required
                    />
                </div>
                <button className='btn btn-primary' type='submit'>Login</button>
            </form>
            <p className='mt-3'>
                Don't have an account? <Link to='/signup'>Sign Up</Link>
            </p>
            <p className='mt-3'>
                Forgot your Password? <Link to='/reset-password'>Reset Password</Link>
            </p>
        </div) 
    );
};

// const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    // is authenticated?
// });

export default connect(null, { })(Login);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn t close the div tag before the input

Comment: Happy if now you get the answer. (If it works, you can maybe close the question)